# How to get URLLoader data dynamically in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, urlloader, loadvars

In an AS3 Flash project I have a .txt file with 90 paramters like:

`st75=15&st2=34&st14=3&` ...and so on until 90.

They are not even sorted from **st1** to **st90**.

I need to be able to get them in a for loop, like:

```
for(var i:Number=1; i<=90; i++) {
var stat = myLoader.data."st"+i;
trace("st"+i+" = "+stat);
}
```

Obviously this will not work, so anybody has any ideea on how to do this?

I've done some searching but I'm afraid I don't even know what keywords to search for.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it like this:

```
var stats:Object = {};
for(var i:Number=1; i<=90; i++) {
  if(myLoader.data["st"+i]){
    stats["st"+i] = myLoader.data["st"+i];
    trace("st"+ i + " is: "+stats["st"+i]);
  }
}
```

Note the syntax: `myLoader.data["st"+i]` and not `myLoader.data."st"+i`